# Javascript Form validation disabled submit without any framework

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, onclick

I am trying to add my own form validation to this form. The aim is at the end to have these rules:

- If email not valid, display an error.
- If text area < 50 char, display an error.
- If all inputs are invalid, disable the submit.

My first aim is to disable the submit. I tried this with many solutions found in the Internet. Unfortunately, without success. My last try is inspired by this post: https://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/form-submit-demo.php.

This is my form:

```
<form name="myForm" action="##" method="post"> 
                        <div class="margin_b">
                            <div class="opinion-radio margin_b">
                                <span class="label-left">How do you like our pizza?</span> <!-- First element of the form -->
                                <div class="checkbox-style inputs-right">
                                    <input id="awesome" type="radio" name="review" value="awesome">
                                    <label for="awesome" class="margin-right">Awesome</label>
                                    <input id="good" type="radio" name="review" value="good">
                                    <label for="good" class="margin-right">Good</label>
                                    <input id="ok" type="radio" name="review" value="ok">
                                    <label for="ok"class="margin-right">Ok</label>
                                    <input id="poor" type="radio" name="review" value="poor">
                                    <label for="poor">Poor</label>
                                </div>
                                <span id="error-review" class="label-left error">Please select a response.</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="opinion-radio">
                                <span class="inline, label-left">What do you think about our prices?</span> <!-- Second element of the form -->
                                <div class="checkbox-style inputs-right">
                                    <input id="fair" type="radio" name="reviewprice" value="fair">
                                    <label for="fair" class="margin-right">Fair</label>
                                    <input id="okay" type="radio" name="reviewprice" value="okay">
                                    <label for="okay" class="margin-right">Okay</label>
                                    <input id="expensive" type="radio" name="reviewprice" value="expensive">
                                    <label for="expensive">Expensive</label>
                                </div>
                                <span id="error-reviewprice" class="label-left error">Please select a response.</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="margin_b">
                            <label for="name" class=" label-left">Your name:</label> <!-- Third element of the form -->
                            <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" class="inline inputs-right">
                            <span id="error-name" class="error label-left">Please add a name.</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="margin_b">
                            <label for="name" class=" label-left">Your e-mail address:</label> <!-- Fourth element of the form -->
                            <input type="email" id="email" name="user_email" class="inline inputs-right">
                            <span id="error-email" class="label-left error">Please add a correct email.</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="margin_b">
                            <label for="msg" class="label-left">What can we do better :</label> <!-- Fifth element of the form -->
                            <textarea id="msg" name="user_message" class="inline inputs-right"></textarea>
                            <span id="error-text" class="label-left error">Please add a correct text of at least 50 characters.</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="align-right">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnsubmit">
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

This is my JS (with a first try with the first question of the form):

```
function formValidation() { 

t1ck=true;

if (!document.getElementById("awesome").checked && !document.getElementById("good").checked && !document.getElementById("ok").checked && !document.getElementById("poor").checked ) { 
    alert("false");
    t1ck=false;
}

if (t1ck == false) {
    var btnsubmit = document.getElementById("btnsubmit");
    btnsubmit.disabled = true;
    btnsubmit.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
} else {
    t1ck=true;
    alert("true");
    btnsubmit.disabled = false; 
    } 
}

function submitCheck() {

  var awesome = document.getElementById("awesome"); 
  var good = document.getElementById("good"); 
  var ok = document.getElementById("ok"); 
  var poor = document.getElementById("poor");

  t1ck=false;
  document.getElementById("btnsubmit").disabled = true;

  awesome.onclick = formValidation(); 
  good.onclick = formValidation(); 
  ok.onclick = formValidation();
  poor.onclick = formValidation(); 
} 
window.onload = submitCheck;
```

What I discovered is that alert("false"), which is here for debugging purposes) will always be called when the page load, even if this is linked with an onclick event. Furthermore, I never achieved to trigger alert("true").

Comment: You may want to consider reading about HTML5 validation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation since browsers now implement most (or maybe all) of what you want natively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define onclick events by calling functions which is wrong.
You need to just use it with function reference without `()` like that:

```
awesome.onclick = formValidation;
```

I guess your button disabling will also work then :)

Comment: Thanks! This was the correct starting point in order to get it right.